# Did not receive exception email in production

Tags: governorlimits, future, queueable-apex

We usually get exception emails to our admin from the production. I have a asynchronous code running in production

```
@future
    public static void processRecords(String FIMCJSONRec)
    {

        List<FIMC_Email_List__c> FIMCBatchRows = (List<FIMC_Email_List__c>) JSON.deserialize(FIMCJSONRec, List<FIMC_Email_List__c>.class);
        List<FIMC_Email_List__c> fcDeleteList = new List<FIMC_Email_List__c>();
        fcDeleteList=[select Id,Name,Static_List_Ref__c from FIMC_Email_List__c where Static_List_Ref__c=: FIMCBatchRows[0].Static_List_Ref__c];

                Database.DeleteResult[] FIMCDelete = Database.delete(fcDeleteList,True); // Do not allow partial success
                // Identifying delete errors
    }
```

Note: I skimmed the code to keep it minimal

Let's say my fcDeleteList is more than 10,000 rows i technically hit governor limit and my code terminates, The last modified user would be admin and exception notification is configured for that admin and admin never received exception emails.

To give more idea this **future call is fired from a queueable class**. Is this normal because admin was able to see the exception message in the apex jobs area?

> EDIT:  Apex Exception Notification is configured

Comment: Did you configure the [Apex Exception Notification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170712&language=en_US&type=1)?

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, like i mentioned in the question we do get other unhandled exceptions emails!

Comment: Well, if you are not the User listed on LastModifiedBy on that class, you won't receive it until you set up the notifications. Are you also the LastModifiedBy on the class here?

Comment: @JayantDas I last modified the class but my admin was configured in the apex Exception Notification and admin didn't receive the notification!

Comment: Okay, so I assume that you still are an active user in the system and that you already have setup an apex notification with some other email id, and still none of you are not able to receive any notification. And also that the email deliverability is not a factor here. Is this all understanding correct?

Comment: @JayantDas I'm not an user in production so,last modified in production would be the admin that deployed the code and the email Exception notification was configured to same admin and no issues in email deliverability!

Comment: So I was reading this in your question -- *In this case **I'm not receiving**(admin) an email.* I don't see any reason why it should not be triggered if last modified by and exception email has been setup, as any unhandled exception triggered from any async transactions are also sent as exception emails. You may like to get a support ticket opened then.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks for pointing this out. I just modified the question. Sure then will try opening a case with support!