# Not Receiving Unhandled Exceptions Emails

Tags: apex, email, exception, platform-bug

I had have a very minimal code to throw null pointer exception intentionally. The reason was we're not receiving exception emails. We even reached out to support(You know how it can be painful process).

```
global class NullPointerBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    global Boolean hasError {get;set;}
    //constructor
    global NullPointerBatch(){
        //  hasError=False; // commented this intentionally to throw null pointer in the start method 
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query ='';
        if(hasError){ // the exception is thrown here
            query = 'select Id,Name From Contact';   
        }
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,  List<sObject> scope) {

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

Technically this error should have sent me an email. In this case Im not recieving any emails. Whats even wierd is if i had any exceptions in process builder or flows, I was able to recieve the emails.

I'm looking at [When are unhandled exception emails suppressed and not sent? or Why do I not always get exception emails even though I've set them up?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219976/when-are-unhandled-exception-emails-suppressed-and-not-sent-or-why-do-i-not-alw/219984).

**Question:** Can this be one of the suppression behavior or Can this be a bug or Am I missing something here?

> Note: I'm the last modifed person and Yes Apex Exception Notification
>   is configured. Also as part of the support they made us do some testing by making us send some emails and declared everything is working as expected. So i wrote the above code to reproduce the behavior.

To tie the original question here. [Did not receive exception email in production](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230767/did-not-receive-exception-email-in-production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well support was able to reproduce the issue and says that when an unhandled exception occurs, their system does throw an **Internal Server Error** type event in logs. They suspect, due to this ISE, apex exception email is getting suppressed and unable to send to the user.

They also pointed me to the idea 
 [Need a reliable developer script exception alert mechanism](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEOdQAM)

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case where you're deliberately generating the error, I'd expect some suppression (eventually)

> If duplicate exceptions occur in Apex code that runs synchronously,
>   subsequent exception emails are suppressed and only the first email is
>   sent.

That is from https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_apex_exceptions.htm&type=5. And you will be generating a duplicate error over and over.

It looks like you've already done your reading around. From having read those Q/As before, I just came to the conclusion that you can't rely on automated error emails from Salesforce. They don't have a clear spec, and the behaviour is just unreliable. So, I end up building somethings myself by logging operations in the database and running reports/dashboards/workflow emails to alert about problems.

If something is critical, then pseudo-code:

```
insert status to say I will attempt X with status=running
try { 
  do X;
  update status to complete;
} catch(Exception e) {
  update status to error with exception details; 
}
```

Then run reports/workflows on any status objects that get stuck in `running` or end up in `error`.

Which doesn't exactly answer your question, but might give you an alternative avenue because those error emails are rubbish.